# How to override UIImageView's image property in an IBDesignable subclass?

Tags: uiimageview, interface-builder

I made a subclass of UIImageView which uses Core Graphics to generate a new image that is cropped to a circle with an optional border. It works fine when I run the app. In Interface Builder, however, the generated image renders properly, but it does so underneath the "no image set" placeholder for a UIImageView. Also, the image property shows up twice in IB, and the new image is only generated if I set the overridden field. If I set the image in the regular UIImageView field, it just acts as though it isn't subclassed. Is this just a bug in IB, or is there a fix?

```
@IBInspectable override var image : UIImage? {
    didSet {
        // Make the image a circle
        makeCircleImage()
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We are stuck with Apple's IB implementation, I'm afraid. I recommend that you find a workaround to overriding `image`. You can instead implement `prepareForInterfaceBuilder` and `awakeFromNib` and do it there, or have a method of doing this operation once in the draw or layout methods, or have a boolean IBInspectable var that does this operation when set.